# Umbraco 7.2.1 ClientDependency

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, client-dependency

When I am trying to go to Umbraco admin page I am getting this error

> ```
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following
> ```
>
> specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does
>   not exist in the namespace 'ClientDependency.Core' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:

I've tried to uninstall and install nuget package again , restarted visual studio (13) , restarted the workstation , removed reference and added again. Nothing help.

Have anyone faced with this kind of problem ?

Comment: Did you build the solution?

Comment: Did you installed using nuget?  Check if you have all DLL's in your binfolder provided in the release (http://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/721)

Comment: Reinstalling of Umbraco core helped